# mutableStateOf mutablelist not updating ui when items in lazycolumn was dragged

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have code to implement drag-and-drop in LazyColumn. So far, the data in the MutableList changes according to the dragged item, but the changes in the order of the data are not triggered, so in the UI not being updated

```
var songList = remember { mutableListOf<SongPlayer>() }

val stateDrag = rememberReorderableLazyListState(
    onMove = { from, to ->
        Log.v("candrage move", from.index.toString() +" to => "+to.index)
        songList = songList.toMutableList().apply {
            add(songList.indexOfFirst {
                it.mediaId == (to.key as SongPlayer).mediaId }, removeAt(songList.indexOfFirst { it.mediaId == (from.key as SongPlayer).mediaId }))
        }
        Log.v("songlist", songList) // <--------- this data updated base on user dragged
}, canDragOver = { draggedOver, _ ->
    true
})

LazyColumn(
    state = stateDrag.listState,
    modifier = Modifier.then(Modifier.reorderable(stateDrag))
) {
    Log.v("moveNewSonglistItems", songList.map { it.songName }) // <------- this is NOT TRIGGERED
    items(songList, { it }) { item ->
        ReorderableItem(stateDrag, item) { isDragging ->
            val elevation = animateDpAsState(if (isDragging) 2.dp else 0.dp)
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .shadow(elevation.value)
                    .padding(vertical = 1.dp)
                    .detectReorder(stateDrag)
            ) {
                SongListItem(
                    songPlayer = item,
                    showCover = true,
                    showDrag = true,
                    onSongClick = {
                    },
                    onOptionClick = {
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How do fix this ?

Comment: You should consider using `mutableStateListOf` instead

Comment: ahh...My mistake, I was not careful enough. now working properly..